# Why does \noindent have such an effect on \rlap and \llap.?

Tags: spacing, positioning

Without \noindent, \rlap and \llap seem to move down by \baselineskip every time.  Is this deliberate?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\color{red}
\rlap{\rule{.25in}{1ex}}\rlap{\rule{.25in}{1ex}}\rlap{\rule{.25in}{1ex}}

\color{blue}
\noindent\rlap{\rule{.25in}{1ex}}\rlap{\rule{.25in}{1ex}}\rlap{\rule{.25in}{1ex}}

\color{green}
\llap{\rule{.25in}{1ex}}\llap{\rule{.25in}{1ex}}\llap{\rule{.25in}{1ex}}

\color{black}
\noindent\llap{\rule{.25in}{1ex}}\llap{\rule{.25in}{1ex}}\llap{\rule{.25in}{1ex}}
\end{document}
```

[image: color bars]

Comment: My take on this is this: Without `\noindent` you're still in vertical mode, stacking horizontal boxes, hence the duplication of `\rlap` in the output. `\noindent` (like `\leavevmode`) starts a paragraph, where the horizontal boxes are overlaid due to the over`lap`ping.

Comment: Piggy-backing on what @werner said, if you read section 16.3 of TeX by Topic, it'll explain what's happening.  You've got to keep in mind that `\rlap` and `\llap` are both defined in terms of an `\hbox`.

Comment: Use `\makebox[0pt][l]{...}` instead of `\rlap` and `\makebox[0pt][r]{...}` instead of `\llap`. Less efficient, perhaps, but safer also with respect to color changes. By the way, avoid `\color` commands between paragraphs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both `\rlap` and `\llap` are defined in terms of an `\hbox`

```
\def\rlap#1{\hb@xt@\z@{#1\hss}}
\def\llap#1{\hb@xt@\z@{\hss#1}}
```

where

```
\def\hb@xt@{\hbox to}
```

However, an `\hbox` cannot be used to start a paragraph.  You either need to explicitly switch to horizontal mode by using something like `\noindent` or `\leavevmode`.  (See section 16.3 of TeX by Topic for further details.)

Here's your MWE behaving a bit more like you probably expected it should:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\aelap[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{#1}}
\begin{document}

\color{red}
\leavevmode\rlap{\rule{.25in}{1ex}}\rlap{\rule{.25in}{1ex}}\rlap{\rule{.25in}{1ex}}

\color{blue}
\noindent\rlap{\rule{.25in}{1ex}}\rlap{\rule{.25in}{1ex}}\rlap{\rule{.25in}{1ex}}

\color{green}
\leavevmode\llap{\rule{.25in}{1ex}}\llap{\rule{.25in}{1ex}}\llap{\rule{.25in}{1ex}}

\color{black}
\noindent\llap{\rule{.25in}{1ex}}\llap{\rule{.25in}{1ex}}\llap{\rule{.25in}{1ex}}

\end{document}
```

[image]